# If I have to do n operations in parallel, should I spawn n threads or n-1

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, locking

Operation: do n sub operations, continue after all have finished.

- Approach 1: spawn `n` thread, have the caller thread join them all
- Approach 2: spawn `n-1` threads for `n-1` operations, The caller thread does one of the operations and joins the `n-1` threads.

Looking for Pros and cons of each approach. Which would be better approach for which use case etc. We can also think implementation-wise. There will be a thread pool of finite threads and multiple such Operations running in the system.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that would greatly depend on the actual value of n.

Ideally, if the n is small, like 3-5 or something, I would go with n-1 threads.
Either way, if the operations you're doing are not very resource intensive, you should be good with either.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to choose option one in most cases.

It results in one more thread but it usually simplifies the actual work that the threads have to do<sup>(a)</sup>:

```
main:
    for i in 1..n:
        start thread t[i] with worker function work
    for i in 1..n:
        wait for thread t[i]
    exit

work:
    just do work
```

By using the second approach, you usually have to have the separate workload function as a *function* to be called by both the main thread and all the worker threads, because worker threads tend to have a very specific (and sometimes restrictive) signature.

```
main:
    for i in 1..n-1:
        start thread t[i] with worker function work
    call workfn
    for i in 1..n-1:
        wait for thread t[i]
    exit

work:
    call workfn

workfn:
    just do work
```

With separate threads doing all the work, you can just do all work in an actual thread function and leave the main thread to do its one job very well, simply joining to all the others.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> A good guideline is that a function should do *one* thing and do it *well.* Just keep in mind that's a *guideline.*

Comment: Let's say I don't care about how complicated either approach makes the code.

Comment: Second option is restrictive in nature, when decision to return result could be made on completion of a subset of workers. Sometimes main thread may decide to not wait for all workers threads to finish. It may return the result as soon as it gets the desired result from one of the worker threads. In option 1 it is free to do so but in option 2, if the work instance which main thread is doing itself is the one taking longest amount of time, then main thread will have to wait for atleast that amount of time before returning the result.

Comment: @prongs: if you don't care about that, make sure you never go for a job anywhere where I have a say in the hiring :-)